# C# - PhantomJS/Selenium - Click event doesn't register on a button inside a modal

Tags: c#, selenium, phantomjs

I'm having some issues with automating a website using PhantomJS/Selenium WebDriver in C#.

Part of the website has a check on addresses; entering in an address it can't verify (or just not entering an address at all) brings up a modal div with buttons in it.  Depending on the situation, it will either give you the closest address, or the option to just continue without an address, but the button always has the same id.  The HTML for this div (for the "no address entered" version) is here:

```
<div id="confirmAddress" class="col-xs-5 active-popupbox">
<div class="row vert-offset-top-2">
<p style="margin-left:55px;" class="h3">No Customer Address Provided</p>
<br>
<div style="margin-left:42px;margin-bottom:0px;" class="modal-body">No Customer Address Was Entered. We recommend having the Customer provide an address.</div>
<br>
<div class="col-xs-6">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left:45px;width:200px;" id="confirmBack" name="confirmBack" align="center">Enter Address</button> &nbsp; </div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="confirmPopUp" name="confirmPopUp" align="center">Proceed with No Address</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The button I need to click is the last button, `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="confirmPopUp" name="confirmPopUp" align="center">Proceed with No Address</button>`

However, despite seemingly being able to find the element in my code and calling Click() on it, grabbing screenshots show that it apparently doesn't register the click since the modal popup stays on the page and the next part errors out due to not finding the elements I'm asking it to find.

Here is the relevant portion of my code:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\user1\Documents\Testing\source0.html",
_driver.PageSource);

_driver.FindElementById("contactinfo_next").Click();
if (_driver.FindElementByClassName("active-popupbox").Displayed)
            {
                _driver.GetScreenshot().SaveAsFile(@"C:\users\user1\documents\testing\screenshot01.png", ImageFormat.Png);
                _driver.FindElementById("confirmPopUp").Click();
            }
            _driver.GetScreenshot().SaveAsFile(@"C:\users\user1\documents\testing\screenshot02.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

I use the class name to find the div since they apparently have different id's depending on whether the address was "not provided" or "wasn't verifiable but a close match was found", but the class is always the same.

I have PhantomJS grabbing the source before clicking the "contactinfo_next" button, which is what brings up the modal div, and have confirmed that no div with class "active-popupbox" exists before the contactinfo_next button is clicked.  "screenshot01.png" does get saved, which means that it is finding the div... but it still doesn't register the button click.

I have tried clicking other elements in the div to bring it "into focus", calling Click() twice on the button, assigning the div to a variable called div and then finding the button using `div.FindElements(By.Id("confirmPopUp"))` and clicking on each element in the collection, nothing has worked.

Has anyone else run into this issue?

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm using the following NuGet packages for this:

- PhantomJS
- Selenium WebDriver PhantomJS cross platform
- Selenium WebDriver Support Classes
- Selenium WebDriver

Comment: How are you using PhantomJS? Did you write your own bindings, or are you using someone else's?

Comment: Oops, probably should've mentioned that.  Using the "Selenium WebDriver PhantomJS cross platform" package from NuGet

Comment: I have no idea how to find out what version of PhantomJS that uses. But that could be important.

Comment: Version 2.1.1 is the version of the .exe that I have in the solution

Comment: That is the latest, so that is *probably* not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I don't know if this is specific to this site that I'm trying to automate, but resizing the PhantomJS viewport worked - in my screenshots, the modal's buttons were overlapping each other.  Not sure why it matters but this is what ended up solving my problem.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

To resize the viewport (requires System.Drawing):

```
_driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1920, 1080);
```

Hope this helps anyone else who has a similar problem in the future